# Excel/VBA/VBS - IE After selecting a value from drop down page not getting refreshed

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, vbscript

Based on the values from `dropdown1`, `dropdown2` will refresh and list the values.

Whenever I'm selecting the values for the `dropdown1` **manually** the page is getting refreshed and `dropdown2` listing the values, But through code I'm unable to do it (when value selected in `dropdown1` page is not getting refreshed, so the `dropdown2` not listing any values).

Code sample:

```
Set objtag1 = objIE.Document.getelementbyId(dropdown1_objID)
objtag1.Value = "drpdwn1_value"                        

'After this page is not getting refreshed

Set objtag2 = objIE.Document.getelementbyId(dropdown2_objID) 
objtag2.Value = "drpdwn2_value" 

'in the above line code getting failed coz no values available in the dropdown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set objtag1 = objIE.Document.getelementbyId(dropdown1_objID)

objtag1.Value = "drpdwn1_value"

objtag1.FireEvent ("onchange")

'here the page is  getting refreshed now

Set objtag2 = objIE.Document.getelementbyId(dropdown2_objID)

objtag2.Value = "drpdwn2_value"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the `onchange` event handler. `objtag2.onchange`

Comment: Thank you ..Its working. I have updated the code as objtag1.FireEvent ("onchange") .I have read in a page that this code is to passing value to an onchange javascript event. so if its vbscript event whether this code will work?–